# Integrity of my transaction is lost with "TransactionInDoubtException" exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, transactions, msdtc

I have a code that tries to insert entries scoped in a MSDTC transaction and if there is insert failure then insertion is retried up to a specific threshold.

Here is the code:

```
while(!SaveToDb){
    .......
 Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(AppConfiguration.RetryInsertionDuringFailureIntervalInMin));
}


    private bool SaveToDb()
    {
        try
        {
         ......
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, option))
            {
                Context.SaveEmail(_emailInfoList);
                Context.SaveSyncState(syncState);
                scope.Complete();
                return true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
         ........
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**And there is this exception encountered:**

> Message : The transaction is in doubt. Stack Trace :    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionStatePromotedIndoubt.PromotedTransactionOutcome(InternalTransaction
>   tx)    at System.Transactions.CommittableTransaction.Commit()    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionScope.InternalDispose()    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionScope.Dispose()    at
>   Presensoft.Exchange2010Puch.Core.PushJob.SaveEmailAndSyncState()
>   InnerException : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904):
>   Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation
>   timed out    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stat  eObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, UInt32 error)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[]
>   buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName,
>   TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout,
>   SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj,
>   Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest
>   transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso,
>   SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean
>   isDelegateControlRequest)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDelegatedTransaction.SinglePhaseCommit(SinglePhaseEnlistment
>   enlistment)

**After this application tries to reinsert the entries and what follows is**

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY
>   KEY constraint 'pk_email'.

It looks to me that without transaction.commit() firing up successfully (partial) commit already took place in the first case(MSDTC exception) which led to the latter exception.

Is there any way I can find out whether the commit has happened when there is **"transaction is in doubt"** exception and roll back the commit if there is any.

Answer (score 1):

According to **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionindoubtexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**:

> This exception is thrown when an action is attempted on a transaction
>   that is in doubt. A transaction is in doubt when the state of the
>   transaction cannot be determined. Specifically, **the final outcome of
>   the transaction, whether it commits or aborts, is never known for this
>   transaction.**
>
> This exception is also thrown when an attempt is made to commit the
>   transaction and the transaction becomes InDoubt.
>
> This is a recoverable error.

**EDIT:**

**For recovery:** 
You have to catch `TransactionInDoubtException`& write compensate logic with apt checks.

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, option))
    {
        try
        {
            Context.SaveEmail(_emailInfoList);
            context.SaveSyncState(syncState);
            scope.Complete();
            return true;
        }
        catch (TransactionInDoubtException ex)
        {
            //check whether any one record from the batch has been partially committed . If committed then no need to reprocess this batch.     

            // transaction scope should be disposed first .

            scope.Dispose();

            if (IsReprocessingNeeded(syncState))
                throw;

            return true;
        }
    }

        /// <returns></returns>
        private bool IsReprocessingNeeded(SyncStateDataModal syncState)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var id = _emailInfoList[0].ID;
                    bool isEmailsCommitted = Context.GetJournalEmail().FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == id) != null;
                    if (!isEmailsCommitted)
                        return true;
                    if (context.EmailSynch(syncState.Id) == null)
                    {
                        context.SaveSyncState(syncState);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(AppConfiguration.RetryConnectionIntervalInMin));
                }
            }
        }
```

**SOURCE** [What is the recovery path for TransactionInDoubtException ?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b88ca922-9939-410a-aaf6-7532f4ba9945/what-is-the-recovery-path-for-transactionindoubtexception-?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: Funny, but that is my answer in msdn :)

Comment: I have added source as reference from where I refer, added it here since I was searching for same but not found answer in Stack Overflow. :).